# querySelector from Bootstrap collapse.js problem

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the querySelector from collapse.js (according to the inspector) since I downloaded bootstrap on my server to make my website faster to load (Google is now mobile first...) and despite what I have searched, I haven't settled the querySelector problem so far.

The problem is the toggle function does not work when clicking on a "collapse" bootstrap class.

I read on another thread I had to replace some code in my bootstrap.js. I haven't changed any code yet. Here's what I have :

```
  getSelectorFromElement: function getSelectorFromElement(element) {
  var selector = element.getAttribute('data-target');

  if (!selector || selector === '#') {
    var hrefAttr = element.getAttribute('href');
    selector = hrefAttr && hrefAttr !== '#' ? hrefAttr.trim() : '';
  }

  try {
    return document.querySelector(selector) ? selector : null;
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
},
```

Another solution is welcome.

Comment: Hi, Mat. Please describe the specific problem you are trying to solve. Your proposed solution isn't working - but the original code being replaced is not shown. Can't help unless we know what you are trying to accomplish and the changes that were made. Showing just the current state of things will not be enough information.

Can you provide:
1. The specific original problem you need solved
2. The original code snippet before the replacement

Comment: My bad, just modified the description. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Mat. Please show us the toggle function you are trying to use, in context (html, js snippets needed). I don't think you should need to modify the Bootstrap library. In general that is bad approach - if you were ever to upgrade that library, your changes would be lost.

Comment: Alright, it's the "data-toggle"="collapse" that doesn't work in "<div class="languages service-box" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" role="navigation" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">"

Comment: Please put source in your description of the problem. Hard to read in a comment. If you can create a jsFiddle or equivalent, that would be even more helpful.

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy Thanks for your help. I just changed the location of bootstrap.js and loaded it using an online link in the "head" and not hosting it in my server. Now it works. Beats me as to why it didn't load probably, but guess I'll never know...

Comment: No problem. Please check my answer, now that we have enough information to troubleshoot. That should clear up any mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that BootStrap is being loaded properly. In Firefox or Chrome developer tools or console, there should be an error if the function being called to collapse the panel is not loaded, when it is called. Also, any failure to load a js file should be reported as an error. Check the path the browser is attempting to load the file from, versus where you think it is located, and see if you can fix the mismatch.

Comment: I did that. That's how I realised it didn't load either. What I didn't get was why it loaded in the CDN and not on the version I had downloaded in my server. I get the collapse.js part was missing...Anyway, thanks for the feedback mate. All is well now. I've loaded it using the normal CDN given by the bootstrap website.